# How to set ImageView to the right side of ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have a image view which I want to set it to the horizontal right side in constraint layout, but the layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf constraint seems not work in imageView.

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            tools:text="text_value" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_keyboard_arrow_right_24" />
```

Comment: its ok for me, can you give me screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Replace words `Start` and `End` with `Right` and `Left` according to your needs:

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRight="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_keyboard_arrow_right_24" />
```

Using words `Start` and `End` when adjusting views in a layout means the layout direction may change according to `locale`, but when you use the words `Right` and `Left`, it means you are specifying the absolute places of `view`s.

Comment: upload an image of layout to better get the idea

Answer (score 0):

Constraint textView at the most start, most top and most bottom of the parent but also its right is left to imageView.

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginStart="16dp" 
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" 
android:textSize="24sp"
app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="+id/imageView"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
```

And, constraint ImageView at the most end, most top and most bottom of the parent but also its left is right to textView.

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp" 
android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
app:layout_constrainLeft_toRightOf="+id/textView"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_keyboard_arrow_right_24" />
```